# if element offset top is at 10% of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to execute a function and detect when my `element.offset().top` is at more or less 10% of my **viewport(window)** when I scroll. How can I proceed?

I have this at the moment.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var wst = $(this).scrollTop();
    var wh = $(this).height();
    var elpos = wrapper.offset().top;

    if (wst >= elpos) {
      console.log('snoop doggy dog');
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help.

**Note:** It's the element position top that needs to be at 10% of the window. not 10% of the document. Thanks.

Comment: Use the condition `if (wst >= wh*0.1) {`

Answer (score 0):

I have written a different implementation for you which will help you accomplish your task. I explain the rest in snippet as comments.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() { /* OnScroll */

    /* Calculate if the scroll position is > 10% */
    if($(document).scrollTop() > (0.1 * $(document).height())) { 
        console.log('Scroll Passed 10%');
    } else {
        /* Less than 10% */
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n9pk9rxh/2/)

---

Didn't got the question quiet well so deleted.

Comment: `(1/10) * $(document).height() === $(document).height()/10` (easier to read imo)

Comment: Omg, i'm sorry, I may have not be very clear. It's the element position top that I need to know if its passed 10% of the window screen, not 10% of the document. Thanks for taking the time btw.

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend setting a flag variable outside of the scroll function this way the action is called once when the statement is true.

```
var flag = true;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var wst = $(this).scrollTop();
    var wh = $(this).height();
    var elpos = wrapper.offset().top;

    if (wst >= elpos*0.1 && flag) {
        flag = false;
        console.log("in")

        tabs.first().addClass('active');

        sections.first().find('figure').addClass('figureAnimateIn');
        setTimeout(function(){
            sections.first().find('.info').addClass('infoAnimateIn');
        }, 300);

    }
});
```